# ExtJs create store in view returns prototype not object

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

## The Problem

I want to create and assign a store to an `Ext.grid.Panel`.
In the `initComponent` of the Panel when I create a new store with `Ext.create()` the **prototype** is returned and not the actual object.

The used **ExtJs** Version is **4.1.1** with `ext-dev.js` included.

**Update**

When I include `ext-all-dev.js` it is working, but when I build the application with **Sencha Cmd** the same error occurse.
But no require warnings are shown in the console.

What do I wrong here? Thank's for any suggestions, ideas..

### Solution

Today I found the solution, it was not dedicated to any of the files listed below.
A file in the app folder which defines a store in the `Ext` namespace caused it.

After removing the file, everything workes like expected.

---

### Exception

Later I get `Cannot read property 'buffered' of undefined` Exception when the store is used the first time.
The property bufferd is tried to accessed but the prototype has no.

### Prototype from Chrome Dev. Console

```
serviceStore: constructor
  __proto__: TemplateClass
  $className: "AP.store.Services"
  allowDeselect: true
  config: emptyFn
  configMap: TemplateClass
  initConfigList: Array[0]
  initConfigMap: Object
  model: "AP.model.Service"
  requires: function constructor() {
  self: function constructor() {
  superclass: TemplateClass
  __proto__: TemplateClass
```

### Grid Panel

```
Ext.define('AP.view.ServiceList', {
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  requires: 'AP.store.Services',
  hideHeaders: true,
  dialogeFilter: null,
  allowDeselect: true,

  initComponent: function() {
      console.log('ServiceList.initComponent()');
      var me = this;

      this.columns = [{
              text: 'Name',
              dataIndex: 'name',
              flex: 1,
              renderer: this.renderServiceCell
         }];

      //after the Ext.Create the above prototype is in the variable serviceStore
      //not the expected object
      var serviceStore = Ext.create('AP.store.Services');
      Ext.apply(me, {
          store: serviceStore
      });

    this.callParent(arguments);
}, ...
```

### Store

```
Ext.define('AP.store.Services', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.ArrayStore',
  requires: 'AP.model.Service',
  model: 'AP.model.Service',
  allowDeselect: true
});
```

### Model

```
Ext.define('AP.model.Service', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: ['id', 'name'],
  allowDeselect: true
});
```

### Grid Panel declarative Definition

I tried it without the `initComponent` function by defining the store the declarative way.
But I also get the Exception `Cannot read property 'buffered' of undefined` ...

```
Ext.define('AP.view.ServiceList', {
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  alias: 'widget.servicelist',
  requires: 'AP.store.Services',

  store :  'Services',
  columns: [{
              text: 'Name',
              dataIndex: 'name',
              flex: 1,
              renderer: this.renderServiceCell
          }],

...
```

Comment: You code seems OK. Are you sure you're not misinterpreting the console output? To me that could be an instance of an Ext class, like it could be a prototype... Or even both!

Comment: Hm I don't thing so. I run step by step through the creation process of the model in the chrome debug view and the prototype above should be the object of the store.

Comment: Instead of doing `Ext.apply`, have you tried doing `this.store = serviceStore`, or possibly putting that logic in the constructor of your grid panel?  Just a thought.

Comment: Yes I tried this also, but it is not working. `Ext.create` is not returning a store object, but a prototype of it...

Comment: Dude, the code you're showing just works: [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2uj)... And again, your diagnostic seems very flaky to me. You should post a question with the real problem you're trying to fix...

Comment: Thank's for your time,yes your fiddle works, but in my project which is a way more complex it is not working at this code place. I found out that when I include `ext-all-dev.js` it is working and with `ext-dev.js` just the prototype is returned. When I build the project with Sencha Cmd it is not working. But no require warnings are open.